# Numeric Value not reccognized

Tags: t-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting this error when INSERT data Numeric value 'Week 5 of Fiscal Month' is not recognized
I do not even have that field shown in the error message in my SQL
Please see the attached code. Without knowing what to look for i am posting here, atleast please point me to a subject that i need to look for

```
INSERT  INTO  FISCAL_WEEK_NEW (
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID,
    FISCAL_WEEK_DATE_ID,
    FISCAL_MONTH_ID,
    FISCAL_QUARTER_ID,
    FISCAL_SEASON_ID,
    FISCAL_YEAR_ID,
    FIRST_DATE_IN_FISCAL_MONTH,
    LAST_DATE_IN_FISCAL_MONTH,
    FISCAL_MONTH_LAST_YEAR,
    FISCAL_MONTH_2_YEAR_AGO,
    FIRST_DATE_IN_FISCAL_QUARTER,
    LAST_DATE_IN_FISCAL_QUARTER,
    FISCAL_QUARTER_LAST_YEAR,
    FISCAL_QUARTER_2_YEAR_AGO,
    FIRST_DATE_IN_FISCAL_SEASON,
    LAST_DATE_IN_FISCAL_SEASON ,
    FISCAL_SEASON_LAST_YEAR,
    FISCAL_SEASON_2_YEAR_AGO,
    FIRST_DATE_IN_FISCAL_YEAR,
    LAST_DATE_IN_FISCAL_YEAR,
    FISCAL_YEAR_LAST_YEAR,
    FISCAL_YEAR_2_YEAR_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_SEQUENCE_NUM,
    FISCAL_WEEK_DISPLAY_NUM,
    FISCAL_WEEK_DESC,
    FISCAL_WEEK_SHORT_DESC,
    FIRST_DATE_IN_FISCAL_WEEK,
    LAST_DATE_IN_FISCAL_WEEK,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_LAST_YEAR,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_2_YEAR_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_LAST_WEEK,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_2_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_3_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_4_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_MONTH_SEQUENCE_NUM,
    FISCAL_WEEK_IN_YEAR_NUM,
    FISCAL_WEEK_IN_MONTH_NUM,
    FISCAL_WEEK_IN_MONTH_NAME,
    FISCAL_WEEK_IN_QUARTER_NUM,
    FISCAL_WEEK_IN_QUARTER_NAME,
    FISCAL_WEEK_CURRENT_IND,
    LAST_COMPLETE_1_FISCAL_WEEK_IND,
    LAST_COMPLETE_2_FISCAL_WEEK_IND,
    LAST_COMPLETE_3_FISCAL_WEEK_IND,
    LAST_COMPLETE_4_FISCAL_WEEK_IND,
    LAST_COMPLETE_5_FISCAL_WEEK_IND,
    LAST_COMPLETE_6_FISCAL_WEEK_IND,
    LAST_COMPLETE_7_FISCAL_WEEK_IND,
    LAST_COMPLETE_8_FISCAL_WEEK_IND,
    LAST_COMPLETE_9_FISCAL_WEEK_IND,
    LAST_COMPLETE_10_FISCAL_WEEK_IND,
    LAST_COMPLETE_11_FISCAL_WEEK_IND,
    LAST_COMPLETE_12_FISCAL_WEEK_IND,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_5_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_6_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_7_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_8_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_9_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_10_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_11_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_12_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_13_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_14_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_15_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_16_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_17_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_18_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_19_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_20_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_21_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_22_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_23_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_24_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_25_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_26_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_27_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_28_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_29_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_30_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_31_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_32_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_33_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_34_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_35_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_36_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_37_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_38_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_39_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_40_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_41_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_42_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_43_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_44_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_45_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_46_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_47_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_48_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_49_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_50_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_51_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_52_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_3_YEAR_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_4_YEAR_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_5_YEAR_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_6_YEAR_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_7_YEAR_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_8_YEAR_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_9_YEAR_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_10_YEAR_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_1_QUARTER_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_2_QUARTER_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_3_QUARTER_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_4_QUARTER_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_5_QUARTER_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_6_QUARTER_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_7_QUARTER_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_8_QUARTER_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_9_QUARTER_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_10_QUARTER_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_1_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_2_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_3_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_4_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_5_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_6_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_7_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_8_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_9_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_10_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_11_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_12_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_13_MONTH_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_LAST_YEAR_2_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_LAST_YEAR_3_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_LAST_YEAR_4_WEEK_AGO,
    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_LAST_YEAR_5_WEEK_AGO,
    CREATE_PROCESS_CD,
    CREATE_USER,
    CREATE_TS,
    UPDATE_PROCESS_CD,
    UPDATE_USER,
    UPDATE_TS
)
with cte as 
(

SELECT DISTINCT A.fiscal_week_id, 
                A.fiscal_week_date_id, 
                A.fiscal_month_id, 
                A.fiscal_quarter_id, 
                A.fiscal_season_id, 
                A.fiscal_year_id, 
                a.first_date_in_fiscal_month, 
                A.last_date_in_fiscal_month, 
                A.fiscal_month_last_year, 
                A.fiscal_month_2_year_ago, 
                A.first_date_in_fiscal_quarter, 
                A.last_date_in_fiscal_quarter, 
                A.fiscal_quarter_last_year, 
                A.fiscal_quarter_2_year_ago, 
                A.first_date_in_fiscal_season, 
                A.last_date_in_fiscal_season, 
                A.fiscal_season_last_year, 
                A.fiscal_season_2_year_ago, 
                A.first_date_in_fiscal_year, 
                A.last_date_in_fiscal_year, 
                A.fiscal_year_last_year, 
                A.fiscal_year_2_year_ago, 
                A.fiscal_week_sequence_num, 
                A.fiscal_week_display_num, 
                A.fiscal_week_desc, 
                A.fiscal_week_short_desc, 
                A.first_date_in_fiscal_week, 
                A.last_date_in_fiscal_week, 
                A.fiscal_month_sequence_num, 
                A.fiscal_week_in_year_num, 
                A.fiscal_week_in_month_num, 
                A.fiscal_week_in_month_name, 
                A.fiscal_week_in_quarter_num, 
                A.fiscal_week_in_quarter_name, 
                A.fiscal_week_current_ind, 
                A.last_complete_1_fiscal_week_ind, 
                A.last_complete_2_fiscal_week_ind, 
                A.last_complete_3_fiscal_week_ind, 
                A.last_complete_4_fiscal_week_ind, 
                A.last_complete_5_fiscal_week_ind, 
                A.last_complete_6_fiscal_week_ind, 
                A.last_complete_7_fiscal_week_ind, 
                A.last_complete_8_fiscal_week_ind, 
                A.last_complete_9_fiscal_week_ind, 
                A.last_complete_10_fiscal_week_ind, 
                A.last_complete_11_fiscal_week_ind, 
                A.last_complete_12_fiscal_week_ind, 
                COALESCE(LW1.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_last_week, 
                COALESCE(LW2.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_2_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW3.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_3_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW4.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_4_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW5.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_5_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW6.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_6_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW7.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_7_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW8.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_8_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW9.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_9_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW10.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_10_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW11.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_11_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW12.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_12_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW13.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_13_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW14.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_14_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW15.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_15_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW16.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_16_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW17.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_17_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW18.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_18_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW19.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_19_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW20.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_20_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW21.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_21_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW22.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_22_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW23.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_23_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW24.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_24_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW25.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_25_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW26.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_26_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW27.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_27_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW28.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_28_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW29.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_29_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW30.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_30_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW31.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_31_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW32.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_32_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW33.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_33_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW34.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_34_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW35.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_35_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW36.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_36_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW37.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_37_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW38.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_38_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW39.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_39_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW40.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_40_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW41.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_41_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW42.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_42_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW43.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_43_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW44.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_44_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW45.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_45_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW46.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_46_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW47.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_47_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW48.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_48_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW49.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_49_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW50.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_50_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW51.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_51_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LW52.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_52_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(B.fiscal_week_id, 0)    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_LAST_YEAR, 
                /*FWIDLY*/ 
                COALESCE(C.fiscal_week_id, 0)    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_2_YEAR_AGO, 
                /*FWID2Y*/ 
                COALESCE(D.fiscal_week_id, 0)    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_3_YEAR_AGO, 
                /* FWI3Y*/ 
                COALESCE(E.fiscal_week_id, 0)    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_4_YEAR_AGO, 
                /*  FWI4Y*/ 
                COALESCE(F.fiscal_week_id, 0)    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_5_YEAR_AGO, 
                /* FWI5Y*/ 
                COALESCE(G.fiscal_week_id, 0)    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_6_YEAR_AGO, 
                /* FWI6Y*/ 
                COALESCE(H.fiscal_week_id, 0)    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_7_YEAR_AGO, 
                /* FWI7Y*/ 
                COALESCE(I.fiscal_week_id, 0)    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_8_YEAR_AGO, 
                /* FWI8Y*/ 
                COALESCE(J.fiscal_week_id, 0)    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_9_YEAR_AGO, 
                /* FWI9Y*/ 
                COALESCE(K.fiscal_week_id, 0)    FISCAL_WEEK_ID_10_YEAR_AGO, 
                /* FWI10Y,*/ 
                ----COALESCE(LW52.fiscal_week_id,0) fiscal_week_id_2_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LQ1.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_1_quarter_ago, 
                COALESCE(LQ2.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_2_quarter_ago, 
                COALESCE(LQ3.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_3_quarter_ago, 
                COALESCE(LQ4.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_4_quarter_ago, 
               COALESCE(LQ5.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_5_quarter_ago, 
                COALESCE(LQ6.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_6_quarter_ago, 
                COALESCE(LQ7.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_7_quarter_ago, 
                COALESCE(LQ8.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_8_quarter_ago, 
                COALESCE(LQ9.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_9_quarter_ago, 
                COALESCE(LQ10.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_10_quarter_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM1.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_1_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM2.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_2_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM3.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_3_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM4.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_4_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM5.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_5_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM6.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_6_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM7.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_7_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM8.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_8_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM9.fiscal_week_id, 0)  fiscal_week_id_9_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM10.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_10_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM11.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_11_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM12.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_12_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LM13.fiscal_week_id, 0) fiscal_week_id_13_month_ago, 
                COALESCE(LY2W.fiscal_week_id, 0) 
                fiscal_week_id_last_year_2_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LY3W.fiscal_week_id, 0) 
                fiscal_week_id_last_year_3_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LY4W.fiscal_week_id, 0) 
                fiscal_week_id_last_year_4_week_ago, 
                COALESCE(LY5W.fiscal_week_id, 0) 
                fiscal_week_id_last_year_5_week_ago, 
                'SQL_SCRIPT' AS CREATE_PROCESS_CD
,'BKANDALA' AS  CREATE_USER
,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS CREATE_TS
,NULL AS UPDATE_PROCESS_CD
,NULL AS UPDATE_USER
,NULL AS UPDATE_TS

FROM   fiscal_week A 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week B 
                    ON A.fiscal_week_id_last_year = B.fiscal_week_id 
                       AND A.fiscal_week_id > B.fiscal_week_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week C 
                    ON A.fiscal_week_id_2_year_ago = C.fiscal_week_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week D 
                    ON A.fiscal_week_id_3_year_ago = D.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week E 
                    ON A.fiscal_week_id_4_year_ago = E.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week F 
                    ON A.fiscal_week_id_5_year_ago = F.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week G 
                    ON A.fiscal_week_id_6_year_ago = G.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week H 
                    ON A.fiscal_week_id_7_year_ago = H.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week I 
                    ON A.fiscal_week_id_8_year_ago = I.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week J 
                    ON A.fiscal_week_id_9_year_ago = J.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week K 
                    ON A.fiscal_week_id_10_year_ago = K.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW1 
                    ON A.fiscal_week_id_last_week = LW1.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW2 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_2_week_ago = LW2.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW3 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_3_week_ago = LW3.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW4 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_4_week_ago = LW4.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW5 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_5_week_ago = LW5.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW6 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_6_week_ago = LW6.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW7 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_7_week_ago = LW7.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW8 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_8_week_ago = LW8.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW9 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_9_week_ago = LW9.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW10 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_10_week_ago = LW10.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW11 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_11_week_ago = LW11.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW12 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_12_week_ago = LW12.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW13 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_13_week_ago = LW13.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW14 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_14_week_ago = LW14.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW15 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_15_week_ago = LW15.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW16 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_16_week_ago = LW16.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW17 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_17_week_ago = LW17.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW18 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_18_week_ago = LW18.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW19 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_19_week_ago = LW19.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW20 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_20_week_ago = LW20.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW21 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_21_week_ago = LW21.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW22 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_22_week_ago = LW22.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW23 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_23_week_ago = LW23.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW24 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_24_week_ago = LW24.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW25 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_25_week_ago = LW25.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW26 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_26_week_ago = LW26.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW27 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_27_week_ago = LW27.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW28 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_28_week_ago = LW28.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW29 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_29_week_ago = LW29.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW30 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_30_week_ago = LW30.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW31 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_31_week_ago = LW31.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW32 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_32_week_ago = LW32.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW33 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_33_week_ago = LW33.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW34 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_34_week_ago = LW34.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW35 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_35_week_ago = LW35.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW36 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_36_week_ago = LW36.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW37 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_37_week_ago = LW37.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW38 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_38_week_ago = LW38.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW39 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_39_week_ago = LW39.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW40 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_40_week_ago = LW40.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW41 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_41_week_ago = LW41.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW42 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_42_week_ago = LW42.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW43 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_43_week_ago = LW43.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW44 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_44_week_ago = LW44.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW45 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_45_week_ago = LW45.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW46 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_46_week_ago = LW46.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW47 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_47_week_ago = LW47.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW48 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_48_week_ago = LW48.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW49 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_49_week_ago = LW49.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW50 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_50_week_ago = LW50.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW51 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_51_week_ago = LW51.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LW52 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_52_week_ago = LW52.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LQ1 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_1_quarter_ago = LQ1.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LQ2 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_2_quarter_ago = LQ2.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LQ3 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_3_quarter_ago = LQ3.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LQ4 
                    ON 
       A.fiscal_week_id_4_quarter_ago = LQ4.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LQ5 
                  ON 
Dateadd(day, -10, A.fiscal_week_id_5_quarter_ago) = LQ5.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LQ6 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_6_quarter_ago = LQ6.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LQ7 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_7_quarter_ago = LQ7.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LQ8 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_8_quarter_ago = LQ8.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LQ9 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_9_quarter_ago = LQ9.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LQ10 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_10_quarter_ago = LQ10.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM1 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_1_month_ago = LM1.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM2 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_2_month_ago = LM2.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM3 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_3_month_ago = LM3.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM4 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_4_month_ago = LM4.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM5 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_5_month_ago = LM5.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM6 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_6_month_ago = LM6.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM7 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_7_month_ago = LM7.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM8 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_8_month_ago = LM8.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM9 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_9_month_ago = LM9.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM10 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_10_month_ago = LM10.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM11 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_11_month_ago = LM11.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM12 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_12_month_ago = LM12.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LM13 
             ON A.fiscal_week_id_13_month_ago = LM13.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LY2W 
             ON 
A.fiscal_week_id_last_year_2_week_ago = LY2W.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LY3W 
             ON 
A.fiscal_week_id_last_year_3_week_ago = LY3W.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LY4W 
             ON 
A.fiscal_week_id_last_year_4_week_ago = LY4W.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fiscal_week LY5W 
             ON 
A.fiscal_week_id_last_year_5_week_ago = LY5W.last_date_in_fiscal_week 
)
select *
from cte;
----COMMIT;
```

Comment: In your data you are getting `string` value `'Week 5 of Fiscal Month' ` instead of `Number`

Comment: there is no such field as 'Week 5 of Fiscal Month'

Comment: You don't have a column with that name or you don't have any data at all with that value?

Comment: The error message isn't telling you the column name, it's telling you the value of the string that is not numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is getting shifted due to delimiter try identifying the column where "Week 5 of Fiscal Month" is getting inserted .To validate the simple option would be to create temporary table with all column as string and then try inserting the record